# Accidentally overwritten Macintosh recovery partition when installing Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, recovery

About a month ago I ditched macOS for Ubuntu on my iMac Late 2009. During the installation I explicitly told Ubuntu to leave the Macintosh recovery partition alone. It did not. I now wish to go back to macOS and I’ve tried the usual CTRL-R variants to enter recovery mode, and I have tried resetting the PRAM. But now I have confirmed that the recovery partition has been overwritten.

So I fired up a VM with a copy of macOS Sierra, downloaded Sierra from the Apple Store and ran createinstallmedia. Hitting option during boot doesn’t show the bootable USB. The usb was reformatted even before I ran createinstallmedia with Journaled GUID.

I’m sure I’m missing something, has anybody ran into this type of issue before?

Comment: You may want to ask your question here:  https://discussions.apple.com/community/desktop_computers/imac_intel

Comment: As you have a running VM, you've potentially a method to use something like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) to get that VM onto the other Mac's drive. CCC will also recreate the recovery partition as part of the process. [I've never actually tried it from a VM, but it might be worth a shot.]

Answer (score 0):

You machine doesn't support internet recovery.  The earliest machines with a firmware update to support internet recovery came out in 2010.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313

Looks like your machine came with a dvd.  You will need to borrow or buy macos on a dvd.  You need to find a dvd with an macOS equal to or later than.
Original OS Mac OS X 10.6.1 (10A2155)
Later OS    Mac OS X 10.6.2 (10C2234)

It might be easier to get a full install dvd for macos 10.7.

You could try cloning a macos system less than or equal to 
Maximum OS  macOS 10.13.6 (17G65)
Typically the last support os runs slow.

Apple still seems to be selling 10.7. 
https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion
I bought it once.  I remember it came as a download.  I do not know if you will be able to install it on your machine. You may be able to convert the download to a boot usb flash drive install. You will need another machine to do this.

Comment: You can still download the Lion Recovery Disk creator free from Apple [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1433?locale=en_GB) which can be used to recreate recovery partition.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19145/how-can-i-create-or-recreate-a-lion-recovery-partition)

Comment: Good to know.  You point to an interesting article.